# Find image of $\{z:2<\Re(z)<3\}$ under $f(z)={z-3\over z-4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find image of $\{z:2<\Re(z)<3\}$ under $f(z)={z-3\over z-4}$. Whatever I do, nothing seems to work, and I am really frustrated with it. I tried everything and it all turns out partial, ambiguous and complex and I can't seem to find a way to even see what $f(\{x=3\})$ is. I could use help here.

Comment: The line $\Re(z) = 3$ becomes a circle in the complex plane, with radius $0.5$ and center at $0.5$. The line $\Re (z) = 2$ becomes a circle with radius $0.25$ and center at $0.75$. Your set is the open set contained between those two circles.

Comment: I know that after repetitive attempts, but what is the process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $f(z)$ you are given is a linear fractional transformation - it takes points in the complex plane and sends them to points in the complex plane. The collection of circles and lines will map to the collection of circles and lines.

My recommendation would be to take points on the line Re$(z)=2$ and find where they go - what is $f(2)$, $f(2-i)$, and $f(2+i)$. Then find points on the line Re$(z)=3$ and fine where they go - what is $f(3)$, $f(3-i)$, and $f(3+i)$. Then take a point in $2<$Re$(z)<3$ and find where it goes - what is $f(\frac{5}{2})$ - to determine what region to shade.

Comment: Almost forgot about the so important properties. Thank you for sorting things out properly.